# Regex - match symbols different from specific symbols plus a specific combnation?

Tags: java, regex

Please help with the following case:
I want to write a regex which mathes anything containg a digit, a number or the combination "\r\n" (new line)
The only thing I've come up with is for the first two conditions:

```
[^\\.\\d] - Anything different from a dot or a digit
```

How to add a specific "word", if you may ("\r\n") ?
Test input:

```
String s = "10.10.10.10&10.10.10.10 10.10.10.10\r\n10.10.10.10\r\n10.10.10.10\r\n10.10.1‌​‌​0.10";
```

I want this input to be splitet into 6 :(
Thanks

Comment: what should be the output??

Comment: @AJ. `10.10.10.10` x 6

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] ipAddresses = s.split("\\s+");
```

the \s class matches any whitespace character. this includes linefeeds
the plus says: minimum once, but also more.

as you changed the "specifications", this should work:

```
String[] ipAddresses = s.split("[^\\d\\.]+");
```

Comment: What if I want to split this:
"10.10.10.10&10.10.10.10\r\n10.10.10.10\r\n10.10.10.10\r\n10.10.10.10\r\n10.10.10.10" ?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to scape `\` : `\\\`

```
[\\.\\d\\\r\\\n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. I figured it out:

```
String regex = "(\\r\\n)|[^\\d\\.]";
```

Splitting the input by anything different from digit or a dot plus \r\n

```
String s = "10.10.10.10 10.10.10.10%10.10.10.10$10.10.10.10\r\n10.10.10.10\r\n10.10.10.10";
    String regex = "(\\r\\n)|[^\\d\\.]";
    String[] arr = s.split(regex);
    System.out.println(arr.length); // outputs 6
```

Comment: why does anything different but a dot or digit not include \r and \n ? you want to match your regex at least once, so you could just add a quantifier (in this case +)